# Java - multi dimensional random access map that actually stores on the file system to minimize JVM heap usage

Tags: java, arrays, performance

Had a program that used map to store everything.

Works fine until inputs increase making heap go up to 30 GB unusable at that point.

So went to embedded SOLR as a solution to manage the document on the file system. It's slow no matter how I tweak it.

Is there some file system only solution i can use for this?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like [MapDB](http://www.mapdb.org/).

Comment: no one suggested that yet? perhaps good for an answer of its own.

Comment: mapdb seems faster. not that much though. embedded solr is hard to beat turns out!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try [Chronicle Map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/tree/master) which stores all for a Map as a single file. It is entirely off heap and you can have 10 TB on a single machine.

Each Map is its own file and doesn't require anything else to be running. If your process dies, nothing is lost.

Comment: Doesn't get much simpler than that now does it

Comment: question for you - how do I search the map in the fastest way?

Comment: i.e. given `CronMap<String, Pojo>` 
How do I search on one of Pojo's fields?

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza The fastest way to look up a field, is to have an index of the possible values, and a list of all the keys which have this value.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Hazelcast](http://hazelcast.org). They provide Map interface, which can be distributed across machines or backed up by off-heap storage. Anyway, you will not need huge heap.

Comment: i'm just reading it to make sure it works first. do you have an example?

Comment: wait... if i just use their Map with default configuration... will it be smart enough to store on file system when needed so that it doesn't kill my heap automagically? or is there some configuration?

Comment: I believe they don't have default implementation of file store. You can read http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#loading-and-storing-persistent-data and http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#using-high-density-memory-store-with-map. Or distribute your map across many JVMs